# Cannot add dynamic data to a list in React

Tags: reactjs

Thanks for the help in advance.I am just learning to code in react js.When i tried to add name,count and date to a list it shows TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleString').I checked my code but was not able to find the solution to this can anybody help me with this.I get this error on my ExpenseDate.js file

```
**App.js**
import {useState} from "react";
import Expense from "./components/Expense/Expense";
import NewExpense from "./components/NewExpense/NewExpense";
const DUMMY_EXPENSES = [
  { id: "e1", title: "title-1", amount: 100, date: new Date(2021, 10, 5) },
  { id: "e2", title: "title-2", amount: 200, date: new Date(2021, 10, 6) },
  { id: "e3", title: "title-3", amount: 300, date: new Date(2021, 10, 7) },
  { id: "e4", title: "title-4", amount: 400, date: new Date(2021, 10, 8) },
  { id: "e5", title: "title-5", amount: 500, date: new Date(2021, 10, 9) }
];
const App = ()=> {
  const [newExpenses,SetNewExpenses]= useState(DUMMY_EXPENSES);
  const AddExpenseHandler = (expense) => {
    SetNewExpenses((newExpenses)=>{
     return [expense,...newExpenses];
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <NewExpense onAddExpense = {AddExpenseHandler} />
      <Expense data={newExpenses} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

**Expense.js**
import { useState } from "react";

import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import ExpensesFilter from "./ExpensesFilter";
import "./Expense.css";

const Expense = (props) => {
  const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState("2020");
  const YearHandler = (selectedYear) => {
    setCurrentYear(selectedYear);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilter selectedNewYear={currentYear} onYearHandler={YearHandler} />
        {props.data.map((expenses) => {
          return  <ExpenseItem 
           title={expenses.title} 
           amount={expenses.amount} 
           date={expenses.date}
          />
        })}
        
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Expense;

**ExpenseItem.js**
import ExpenseDate from "./ExpenseDate";
import Card from "../UI/Card";
import "./ExpenseItem.css";

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card className="expense-item">
      <ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
      <div className="expense-item__description">
        <h2>{props.title}</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="expense-item__price">
        <h2>{props.amount}</h2>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ExpenseItem;

**ExpenseDate.js**

import './ExpenseDate.css';

const ExpenseDate= (props)=> {
    const month = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
    const day = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', { day: '2-digit' });
    const year = props.date.getFullYear();


  return (
      <div className="expense-date">
        <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
        <div className="expense-date__day">{day}</div>
        <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default ExpenseDate;
```

Images of form  [FORM AND LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLpIK.png) 
Images of Error
[Error is like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3fcc.png)

Answer (score 0):

replace the jsx for Expense Component

```
<div>
      <Card className="expenses">
        <ExpensesFilter selectedNewYear={currentYear} onYearHandler={YearHandler} />
        {
          props.data.map(expenses => 
           <ExpenseItem key={expenses.id}
           title={expenses.title} 
           amount={expenses.amount} 
           date={expenses.date}
           />
          )
       }
        
      </Card>
    </div>
```